# MySQL : Get critical path time

Tags: mysql

I have to manage a gantt like interface where we can have multiple project (`project_id`). And need to get the minimum time to accomplish a project

My tables are the following :

**Task**

```
+---------+-------+----------------+
| id_task | name  | days_allocated |
+---------+-------+----------------+
|       1 | task1 | 2              |
|       2 | task2 | 3              |
|       3 | task3 | 0.5            |
|       4 | task4 | 4              |
+---------+-------+----------------+
```

**Task_predecessor** (both field are linked to `Task.id_task`)

```
+------+-------------+
| task | predecessor |
+------+-------------+
|    2 |           1 |
|    3 |           1 |
|    4 |           2 |
|    4 |           3 |
+------+-------------+
```

**Progress**

```
+-------------+---------+------------+---------+
| id_progress | task_id | project_id | current |
+-------------+---------+------------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |          1 |       0 |
|           2 |       2 |          1 |       1 |
|           3 |       3 |          1 |       1 |
|           4 |       4 |          1 |       1 |
|           5 |       1 |          2 |       0 |
|           6 |       2 |          2 |       0 |
+-------------+---------+------------+---------+
```

So the **Task** table is our "template" and we track the advancment in the **Progress** table.

In this case, for `project_id = 1`, the `id_task 1` is already done (`progress.current` is `0` where `project_id = 1 AND task_id = 1`)

So it's either tasks `id_task 2` + `id_task 4` or `id_task 3` + `id_task 4`.

`id_task 2` take more time than `id_task 3` so the critical path is `id_task 2 --> id_task 4` , 7 days

I have **2 options** :

---

### Option n°1

I can add a `minimal_days` column in my **Task** table because I know the predecessors. So the table will be

```
+---------+-------+----------------+--------------+
| id_task | name  | days_allocated | minimal_days |
+---------+-------+----------------+--------------+
|       1 | task1 | 2              | 9            |
|       2 | task2 | 3              | 7            |
|       3 | task3 | 0.5            | 4.5          |
|       4 | task4 | 4              | 4            |
+---------+-------+----------------+--------------+
```

And I can retrieve the minimal days with this kind of query :

```
SELECT MAX(minimal_days) FROM progress 
LEFT JOIN task ON task.id_task = progress.task_id
WHERE project_id = 1 AND current = 1
```

---

### Option n°2

I rewrite the logic in a MySQL query ? But honestly, I dont know how ...

---

Option n°1 can be easily  implemented, the result will be nearly instantaneous but the system is pretty limited, if a task is added or removed, all `days_allocated` must be recalculed and updated.

Option n°2 is in my opinion most difficult to write in MySQL. The request may be slower. Especially if we have to retrieve it for several projects at once. Once agin is a suposition... But the system will be more modular.

---

I prefear the option n°2, what about you ? Should I prefear another option ? Is there any other way to proceed ? Can you help me to write this logic in MySQL ?

---

PS : We can work with a total of 50 - 100 project at a time. A project can have 30 tasks max and the task_predecessor thing is pretty linear. We don't have very complex schema. So I think the result can be displayed in "real-time"